# Merge all rectangles in an array with each other

Tags: arrays, merge, rectangles, godot, gdscript

I have an array of rectangles and I want to merge all overlapping and adjacent rectangles into each other. The final array should have no overlapping or adjacent rectangles. I tried doing the below code but some rectangles are still left over.

```
func combine_boxes(boxes: Array) -> void:
    var merged := true
    while merged:
        merged = combine_all_overlapping_box(boxes)


func combine_all_overlapping_box(boxes: Array) -> bool:
    var box: Rect2 = boxes[0]
    # Remove our box
    boxes.remove(0)
    # Start from the back of the the array so removals are easier and don't invalidate the index
    var merged := false
    for j in range(boxes.size()-1, -1, -1):
        var collider: Rect2 = boxes[j]
        if overlap_adjacent(box, collider):
            box = box.merge(collider)
            # Remove collider box
            boxes.remove(j)
            merged = true
    # Either add the merge box in, or the unaltered box we remove at the start
    boxes.append(box)
    return merged
```

Comment: When two rectangles overlap, the combined shape is not necessarily (and most-likely not) a rectangle. How do you want to handle those cases?

Comment: At least I can tell for certain that your code would fail if the `boxes` array is empty. And that without `overlap_adjacent` I cannot test it.

Comment: Bigger rectangle

Answer (score 0):

This what I have been able to come up with:

```
func combine_rects(rects: Array) -> Array:
    var result := rects.duplicate()
    var merged := true
    while merged:
        merged = false
        rects = result
        result = []
        while rects.size() > 0:
            var current_rect:Rect2 = rects.pop_back()
            for index in for index in range(rects.size() - 1, -1, -1):
                var other_rect:Rect2 = rects[index]
                if current_rect.intersects(other_rect, true):
                    merged = true
                    current_rect = current_rect.merge(other_rect)
                    rects.remove(index)

            result.append(current_rect)

    return result
```

Let us look at the inner loop first:

```
var current_rect:Rect2 = rects.pop_back()
for index in for index in range(rects.size() - 1, -1, -1):
    var other_rect:Rect2 = rects[index]
    if current_rect.intersects(other_rect, true):
        merged = true
        current_rect = current_rect.merge(other_rect)
        rects.remove(index)

result.append(current_rect)
```

As you can see I remove an element from `rects` and store it in `current_rect`. Then iterate over the rest of the elements, comparing it with them. I use `intersects` with `true` as second argument so it also considers adjacent rects as intersecting… If they intersect, I merge them. And also remove the other element with `rects.remove(index)`… I iterate backwards so I don't have to adjust the `index`.

Since I set the `current_rect` with the result of the merge (`current_rect = current_rect.merge(other_rect)`), I can continue merging more rects into it in the same loop.

Finally I add whatever I ended up with to the `result`.

If we look at the mid loop, we see that I do this until I exhaust `rects`:

```
while rects.size() > 0:
    var current_rect:Rect2 = rects.pop_back()
    for index in for index in range(rects.size() - 1, -1, -1):
        var other_rect:Rect2 = rects[index]
        if current_rect.intersects(other_rect):
            merged = true
            current_rect = current_rect.merge(other_rect)
            rects.remove(index)

    result.append(current_rect)
```

Since I only remove from `rects` (either by `pop_back` or by `remove`) it must eventually be empty and the loop ends.

Now look at the broader picture:

```
func combine_rects(rects: Array) -> Array:
    var result := rects.duplicate()
    var merged := true
    while merged:
        merged = false
        rects = result
        result = []
        while rects.size() > 0:
            var current_rect:Rect2 = rects.pop_back()
            for index in for index in range(rects.size() - 1, -1, -1):
                var other_rect:Rect2 = rects[index]
                if current_rect.intersects(other_rect):
                    merged = true
                    current_rect = current_rect.merge(other_rect)
                    rects.remove(index)

            result.append(current_rect)

    return result
```

We will continue looping as long as we merged something. The `merged` variable keeps track of that. I set it to `true` so the flow of execution enters the loop (the alternative would have been to make an infinite loop `while true` and use `break`).

For the loop we need to make sure `merged` starts `false`, and `result` is empty. So we do that. But also, we want to iterate over the results of the past iteration. Which is why I set `rects = result`. And that means that I need the starting `rects` in `result`. I took the opportunity to work on a copy (`var result := rects.duplicate()`).

You should be able to use it like this:

```
boxes = combine_rects(boxes)
```